# Motorola MTP Device cannot install

Tags: android, usb, driver, motorola

I'm trying to use the Motorola USB driver so I can debug an android app on my phone through Eclipse. However, when I plug in my phone, I get an error on the Found New Hardware Wizard:

Cannot Install this Hardware

There was a problam installing (Motorola MTP Device)

An error occurred during the installation of the device

The required section was not found in the INF

I recently got a new disk drive and had to reinstall the USB driver and the Android SDK, and the USB driver worked on my old disk, so there is nothing wrong with the phone or how it's set up. Does anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to uninstall the driver and reinstall it again. You can also try using **[Universal Adb Driver](https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver)** software. It works on most of the phones and other similar software exist.